# SQL Server 2012 not getting values from subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am pretty new to SQL Server 2012 and I am doing an exercise where I am trying to obtain
1)The EmployeeID, LastName, and FirstName for each employee
2)The OrderID and the total price of the most expensive order 
3)The ShipName

I have gotten most of the way there, getting all the info for each employee and the total price of their most expensive order.

Here is the code I have gotten done so far:

`select e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, max(od.totPrice) as mostExpTotOrder
from Employees e
inner join
Orders o
on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
inner join
(
    select OrderID, sum(unitprice) as totPrice
    from [Order Details]
    where discount = 0
    group by OrderID
) od
on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
group by e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName`

When I try to enter in o.OrderID and o.ShipName to the outer query, the query grabs every OrderID, whereas I am just trying to get the OrderID of the most expensive order each employee has processed.

`select e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, max(od.totPrice) as mostExpTotOrder, o.OrderID, o.ShipName
from Employees e
inner join
Orders o
on e.EmployeeID = o.EmployeeID
inner join
(
    select OrderID, sum(unitprice) as totPrice
    from [Order Details]
    where discount = 0
    group by OrderID
) od
on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
group by e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, o.OrderID, o.ShipName`

Am I missing something pretty basic?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the order Id to the aggregation, Then you get what you ask for.

You are getting the max price per employee PER ORDER.

You didn't mention in any way in your query that you want the order for which the max price was associated to.

To achieve that, you'll need to join the Aggregated Query by the employee Id with the original query, for example by the employee Id and the Price (Assuming both will identify the row uniquely) and then select the order Id.

A small sample to demonstrate:

```
SELECT  *
into #tmp
FROM    
(
    select 1 as OrderId , 1 as EmployeeId , 100 as Price
        UNION
    select 2 as OrderId , 1 as EmployeeId , 200 as Price
        UNION
    select 3 as OrderId , 2 as EmployeeId , 100 as Price
        UNION
    select 4 as OrderId , 2 as EmployeeId , 200 as Price
        UNION
    select 5 as OrderId , 2 as EmployeeId , 300 as Price
) a

SELECT  a.* , b.OrderId
FROM    (
SELECT  EmployeeId , Max(Price) Price
FROM    #tmp a
group by EmployeeId 
) a
    inner join #tmp b
        on a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
        and a.Price = b.Price
```